# Python - Need to drop all data in the dataframe, where the value of one specific column contains at least 1 letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have one data set and one of the columns has values such as: 001, 002, XXX, R02, T01, 003, 004.
I need to drop all rows from the data set where the values of that column have at least 1 letter in the format (R02, T01, XXX) and leave just the number formats. 
In other words, I need to keep all the data where that column has the following values: 001, 002, 003, 004.

I have tried to use the following function, but I had no luck.

```
searchfor = ['r', 't']
Filtered_Table = Filtered_Table[~Filtered_Table.ToBeDeleted2.str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]
```

Comment: For the next time you ask a question, please consider adding  a reproductable example. E.g here adding creation of test Data Frame. It'll save time to people who want to help and increase you'r chance to get an answer

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do what you are trying to do with pandas.

Using df.drop()

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_dropping_column_and_rows/

Those are two helpful links for how the function works.

You can also try using the Regex re.search method.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Answer (score 1):

Python is case sensitive so you need to use below to search ['R', 'T']

searchfor = ['R', 'T']
Filtered_Table = Filtered_Table[~Filtered_Table.ToBeDeleted2.str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]

Demo:

```
import pandas as pd
Filtered_Table = pd.DataFrame([['001', '002'], ['R02', 'XXX'], ['T01', '003'], ['007', '008']], columns=["ToBeDeleted2", "ColB"])

searchfor = ['R', 'T']
Filtered_Table = Filtered_Table[~Filtered_Table.ToBeDeleted2.str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]

Input:
ToBeDeleted2    ColB
0   001        002
1   R02        XXX
2   T01       003
3   007       008

Output:
    ToBeDeleted2    ColB
    0   001        002 
    3   007       008
```